# Excel Array Formula - Multiple column COUNTIFS function in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, match, multiple-columns

I am trying to look in 6 columns for a name and also matches with today's date.

Example:

Column A has each day of the year

Column E through J can have a persons name in it.

Essentially (generic format):

```
{If(countifs(date column, today(), name columns E:J, name) > 0, "PTO", "" )}
```

What I made work, is using 6 countifs added together to count each column, but I know there has to be an array function that can do it. Arrays are not my strong suit but I'm trying to learn them.

My sheet has each day of the year in column A, then names in column E through J. The function is on the same sheet as my criteria and refers to my calendar sheet for the search. Here's what I had tried to make work in an array, but obviously, it doesn't work.

```
{=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS('PTO Calendar'!$A$4:$A$370,Today(), 'PTO Calendar'!$E$4:$J$370, $A5))>0, "PTO", "")}
```

The function is supposed to look for a date match in the first criteria. In my second criteria, I'm trying to search 6 different columns for a name match and then add it all together. It should only ever return a "1" or "0". If >0, then return "PTO", if zero, then "".

Some help understanding why my array won't work would be helpful.

**Excel file will be running online through sharepoint**